# Cant set required attribute in textarea after selected value

Tags: javascript, html, attributes

I have problem with change attribute in textarea.

```
<select class="requiredScript" required>
   <option value="">Select something</option>
   <option value="option1">name1</option>
   <option value="option2">name2</option>
   <option value="option3">*name3</option>
</select>
<textarea placeholder="Enter Additional Information" class="addInfo" rows="8"></textarea>


JavaScipt:
let addInfo = document.querySelector('.addInfo');
let requiredScript = document.querySelector('.requiredScript');


if (requiredScript.value == 'option3') {
    addInfo.required = true;
    console.log('its working');
} else addInfo.removeAttribute('required');
```

When I chose third option "*name3" then I have no message even in console. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Why would you expect value *"Painted"* when choices are only `1,2 & 3`? Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Where/when exactly is your script run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code only runs on page load. You need to add an [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) if you want your attribute to change when you select another option:

```js
let addInfo = document.querySelector('.addInfo');
let requiredScript = document.querySelector('.requiredScript');

requiredScript.addEventListener('change', () => {
  if (requiredScript.value == 'option3') {
    addInfo.required = true;
    console.log('it is working');
  } else addInfo.removeAttribute('required');
})
```

```html
<select class="requiredScript" required>
  <option value="">Select something</option>
  <option value="option1">name1</option>
  <option value="option2">name2</option>
  <option value="option3">*name3</option>
</select>
<textarea placeholder="Enter Additional Information" class="addInfo" rows="8"></textarea>
```